# Does MySQL has concurrent control on generating auto-increment value?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, auto-increment, identity

My colleague provides me a code segement that simulates Oracle's sequence:

```
    // generate ticket
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( "insert seq_pkgid values (NULL);" );
    if(pstmt.executeUpdate() > 1) {
        success = 1;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Generating seq_pkgid sequence failed!");
    }
    pstmt.close();
    pstmt = null;
    // get ticket
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( "select last_insert_id() as maxid" );
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    if( rs.next() ) {
        nSeq = rs.getInt( "maxid" );
    }
    rs.close();
    rs = null;
    pstmt.close();
    pstmt = null;
```

But I wonder what if this code segment executed from 2 instances about the same time. Will they get same generated auto-increment value? Does MySQL has concurrent control, e.g. critical section or semaphore, when generating a new auto-increment value?

Comment: Yes ! If the column has AUTO_INCREMENT in column definition, MySQL will have an Auto Increment Lock on the column. Please refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: @Praveen: Thanks. Maybe you should make your comment as an answer.

Comment: Answer has been posted @ScottChu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ! If the column has AUTO_INCREMENT in column definition, MySQL will have an Auto Increment Lock on the column. Please refer 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to generate a counter from DB, you can read here how to do on MySQL using InnodDB and Locking Reads.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Buy I'm wondering if you really need an autoincrement field or just a uniq identifier for the object you want to store; in this case maybe a UUID() is just fine:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

Comment: Thanks! But due to some reason, I can't use UUID() at current project.